# MVC Unit Of Work

Tags: c#, oop, unit-of-work

I saw some examples of applications using ASP.NET MVC Unit of Work in the context class to perform a commit of transactions.

This is a good practice??

```
public interface IUnitOfWork
{
    void Commit()
}

public class DatabaseContext : DbContext, IUnitOfWork
{
    public DbSet<Entity> Entity { get; set; }

    public void Commit()
    {
        base.SaveChanges();
    }
}

public class EntityRepository : IRepository<Entity>
{
    private DatabaseContext _context;

    public EntityRepository(DatabaseContext Context)
    {
        _context = Context;
    }

    void Insert()
    {
        _context.Entities.Add(Entity);
    }

    void Save()
    {
        _context.Commit();
    }
}
```

Or its better

```
public interface IUnitOfWork
{
    void Commit()
}

public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Entity> Entity { get; set; }
}

public class EntityRepository : IRepository<Entity>, IUnitOfWork
{
    private DatabaseContext _context;

    public EntityRepository(DatabaseContext Context)
    {
        _context = Context;
    }

    void Insert()
    {
        _context.Entities.Add(Entity);
    }

    void Commit()
    {
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

I dont know about this approuch, what u say????

Comment: If all that exists in `Commit` is `base.SaveChanges()` I'm not sure where the value is here. Further, you clearly haven't actually implemented this because the code you have wouldn't even compile.

Answer (score 0):

this is part of the class that I implemented

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private ModelEntities _context;

    public ModelEntities Context
    {
        get { return _context; }
        set { _context = value; }
    }
    public UnitOfWork(ModelEntities context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    public void Save()
    {
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.Dispose(true);
    }
    public void Dispose(bool dispose){
        _context.Dispose();
    }
}
```

In addition to that, we're using a Factory to obtain an instance of UnitOfWork

Answer (score -1):

I think you should change how you create your repositories. The idea of unit of work is to have a unique object for all the transactions. Consider changing the constructor of your repositories to receive the unique unit of work and not a context.

Take a look at:

https://aarcoraci.wordpress.com/2017/02/15/asp-net-mvc5-entity-framework-repository-pattern-and-unit-of-work-revisited/